# node js Stream vs Async

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm writing a node js app to basically process data through a few different pipelines. A sample pipeline might be:

1. Parse XML file into items, for each item
2. Query an API for the item
3. Transform the API results into a standardized model
4. Save the results of the API in MongoDB

I initially implemented this using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library, and it works pretty well. I started investigating an alternate implementation using native Node Streams. This seems to have the advantage of making my code a little more modular (everything is a Readable, Transform, or Writeable) and it's one less library I need to use.

What are the disadvantages to using to using Streams? Am I better off sticking with async?

Comment: Hat's off to Doug McIlroy, despite all the hype around 'how bad is callback hell', async, co-routines or promises, I found out that streams is more sane when you want a better way dealing with asynchronous code, if you have issue down the pipeline just cork it and go beyond memory limitation with the backpressure system

Answer (score 2):

I've used both and so far I'm finding the stream interface to be a lot more sane for this sort of processing.

The nice thing about streams is the input and output methods are completely standardized, so any given stream should be able to fit into any other, presuming they're in a compatible mode (object vs. string). They also allow easy inspection of intermediate values. The [event-stream](https://www.npmjs.org/package/event-stream) library makes it very easy to compose streams, most requiring little more than a function that performs the key operation.

Instead of async, you might want to try using promises using a library like [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), which is a lot like that but has a lot more finesses in how you can handle errors, create complicated chains of events with optional steps, and to propagate responses.

Promises work very well when you need to consume the output of an asynchronous call, and when these operations aren't part of a pipeline that operates on a large number of elements sequentially or in parallel.

Obviously you can do everything without promises or streams, but these patterns allow you to express your logic in a cleaner, more manageable manner.

Comment: Do you have any examples of using streams for this type of processing? I had a blast at it (new to node) and couldn't figure it so ended up with using async which I am not sure is the best tool for the job

Comment: @iwayneo Try playing around in the [NodeJS Streams Playground](http://nodestreams.com/) to get a sense of how flexible and functional they are.